# How to read a complex include variables in Ansible

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

I have a variable file that has multiple variables "name" & "path" listing under an IP address like below.

```
10.0.0.12
    - name: exe_folder
      path: /tmp/exe
    - name: log_folder
      path: /tmp/log
    - name: src_folder
      path: /tmp/src

10.0.0.13
    - name: test_folder
      path: /tmp/exe1
    - name: out_folder
      path: /tmp/log1
    - name: com_folder
      path: /tmp/src1

 etc ....
```

I can loop on the name and path successfully in my playbook as below.

```
   - name: Load repository
     include_vars:
       file="{{ playbook_dir }}/vars/list.yml"
       name=user1

   - debug:
       msg: "{{ item.name + ':' + item.path }}"  
     loop: "{{ user1[inventory_hostname] }}"  

   - set_fact:
       allinonecmd: "{{ allinonecmd | default('') + 'ls -ltr ' + item.path + ' '}}"  
     loop: "{{ user1[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

My requirement is to have a new variable "mycode" under each IP however just have a single mention of it and I should be able to print it in the loop like above playbook does.

Thus i need my variable file to have mycode specified onetime for each IP. I'm not sure what changes I need to make to my variable file and playbook to accomodate this requirement.

```
10.0.0.12
    - name: exe_folder
      path: /tmp/exe
      mycode: "56.12"
    - name: log_folder
      path: /tmp/log
    - name: src_folder
      path: /tmp/src

10.0.0.13
    - name: test_folder
      path: /tmp/exe1
      mycode: "76.88"
    - name: out_folder
      path: /tmp/log1
    - name: com_folder
      path: /tmp/src1

 etc ....
```

The playbook fails after I make the above changes and try to print the mycode variable.

```
   - debug:
       msg: "{{ item.name + ':' + item.path + item.mycode }}"  
     loop: "{{ user1[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

Error Output:

```
fatal: [10.0.0.12]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'mycode'
```

Note: I do not wish to specify mycode multiple times under an IP as it looks like a dirty solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that for this use case, you can use default() filter, so if this element is not on the list, you can recall a default one or omit it.

```
vars:
  my_default_value: "56.12"

   - debug:
       msg: "{{ item.name + ':' + item.path + (item.mycode | default(my_default_value) }}"       loop: "{{ user1[inventory_hostname] }}"
```

Even you can make a combination with default(value) and default(omit) to fit your needs.

Comment: the default has to be pulled from the variable file under that very IP. So the default for 10.0.0.12 has to be 56.12 while for IP 10.0.0.13 it's has to be 76.88 and likewise for all different IP. Your solution hard-coded the ccode as default when it should be looked up from the variable file

Comment: You can create a map of default values instead of a simple variable, only to avoid duplication, with this you can use the solution that I provide earlier or use any of the map / filtering dicts function that Ansible has, to create the final dicts as you want.